# How do I test a Snort rule for the IIS "Integer Overflow in IPP Service Vulnerability"?

Tags: security, iis

I need to make an attack that exploits this vulnerability, on the internet i only could find the description of the vulnerability that is:

> Integer overflow in the Internet Printing Protocol (IPP) ISAPI extension in Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS) 5.0 through 7.0 on Windows 2000 SP4, XP SP2 and SP3, Server 2003 SP1 and SP2, and Server 2008 allows remote authenticated users to execute arbitrary code via an HTTP POST request that triggers an outbound IPP connection from a web server to a machine operated by the attacker, aka "Integer Overflow in IPP Service Vulnerability."

I have no idea how to make this http post. Actually i don't need to complete the attack, I only have to do it so I can show that the snort rule is working.